# Domino 6.5 - close document in frameset - closes app

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus

I'm working on a Domino Client application that opens documents up in a frameset.

When I click the save button it does some lotus script validation, adds to history field and etc then finally does a save:

Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim validate1 As Validation
    Dim ws As New NotesUIworkspace
    Dim s As New NotesSession
    Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
    Dim approverNames As String
    Dim workflow1 As Workflow
    Dim name1 As String
    Dim names1 As String
    Dim item1 As NotesItem
    Dim history1 As History

```
Set uidoc = ws.CurrentDocument
Call uidoc.refresh  

'===============================================
'Validation
'===============================================
Set validate1 = New Validation()

Call validate1.checkCustomer(uidoc.FieldGetText("Customer"))
Call validate1.checkEndUser(uidoc.FieldGetText("EndUser"))
Call validate1.checkShortProjectDescription(uidoc.FieldGetText("ShortProjectDescription"))
Call validate1.checkProjectName(uidoc.FieldGetText("ProjectName"))
Call validate1.checkProjectLocation(uidoc.FieldGetText("ProjectLocation"))
Call validate1.checkOperationCenter(uidoc.FieldGetText("BusinessUnit"))
Call validate1.checkSalesCenter(uidoc.FieldGetText("SalesCenter"))
Call validate1.checkMarketSegment(uidoc.FieldGetText("MarketSegment"))  
Call validate1.checkSAPDate(uidoc.FieldGetText("SAPDate"))
Call validate1.checkRevision(uidoc.FieldGetText("Revision"))
Call validate1.checkValidityDate(uidoc.FieldGetText("ValidityDate"))
Call validate1.checkDateApproval(uidoc.FieldGetText("DateApproval"))
Call validate1.checkCurrencyUSD(uidoc.FieldGetText("CurrencyUSD"))
Call validate1.checkMargin(uidoc.FieldGetText("Margin"))

If validate1.displayErrorMessages() = 0 Then
'========================================================================
    Call uidoc.FieldSetText("WhoHasApproved","")
    Call uidoc.FieldSetText("ApproversNotified","")     

    Call uidoc.FieldSetText("SubmitDate",Cstr(Now))
    Call uidoc.FieldSetText("Status","In Process")

    'Add calls to workflow here....
    Set workflow1 = New workflow("SAPFCD")

    'Update History Field - Submitted for Processing by
    Set history1 = New History(uidoc.Document)
    Call history1.addTo("Submitted for Processing", uidoc.FieldGetText("CreatedBy"))    
    Set item1 = uidoc.Document.ReplaceItemValue("History" , history1.getDescription())

    'Set ApproverList
    names1 = workflow1.setApproverList(uidoc)
    Call uidoc.FieldSetText("ApproverList",names1)

    uidoc.Refresh

    name1 = workflow1.setNextApprover(uidoc)        
    Call uidoc.FieldSetText("NextApprover", name1)
'========================================================================   

    'Add calls to workflow here....
    Call uidoc.FieldSetText("Status","1st Peer")

    uidoc.Save
    uidoc.Close(True)
    uidoc.Close(True)
End If
```

End Sub

and then proceeds to close the entire database and returns user to workspace.

What I want is to have the document saved and then return the user to a specified page in the frame set.

I attempted to add code like this to the QuerySave event, but does not work:

Sub Queryclose(Source As Notesuidocument, Continue As Variant)
    Dim ws As New NotesUIworkspace
    ws.OpenFrameSet("MainFrame")
ws.SetTargetFrame("Main")
ws.OpenPage("Saved")
End Sub

Any ideas on how I can save/close a UI document that is in a frame set without it closing the entire database.

Derek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any specific reason why you have the document open within a frame of a frameset?
Usually you have a frameset for the outline and view and documents open on their own tab/window, this way when the code you have runs it only closes the doc.

**Update
Did some more testing and you can insert this after the uidoc.save and remove uidoc.close

```
Call ws.SetTargetFrame("your frame name here") 
Call ws.ComposeDocument("","","your form name here",,,False)
```

I forgot to mention you should set the target frame back to "" when exiting the app, if you don't users might get error when other apps try to open up a frameset.

Comment: Did some more testing and you can insert this after the uidoc.save and remove uidoc.close

Call ws.SetTargetFrame("your frame name here")
Call ws.ComposeDocument("","","your form name here",,,False)

Comment: I was asked to put document in frame because users were getting confused by having multiple documents open...  I kept tell them that it is a training issue and that is how Mail works... but they didn't want to hear it.....

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine if you only include one uidoc.close event instead of the two you have showing.

Also make sure none of the Form events PostSave/PostClose or QuerySave/QueryClose call a close event.